# p.stdout.read() doesn't work in my Python 3 codes

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I try to create a sub-process using the subprocess module in MAC OS. Below is my code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("app",
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
        shell = True)
p.stdin.write(bytes("3\n", "ascii"))
p.stdin.write(bytes("4\n", "ascii"))
print(p.stdout.read())
```

The source code of app is :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cout << "input x: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "input y: " << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << x + y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the python code, the output is :

```
b''
```

Why the output is that weird string?

Comment: I assume `app` works as expected when run on its own from the command line?

Comment: Yeah, I double checked that.

Comment: Just a little tip: Instead `bytes("3\n", "ascii")`, you could simply write `b"3\n"`.

Comment: Thanks the advise, @Dolda2000 ! And btw, I tried to remove the b character before the string, and there's a new error: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface. Do you know what problem is it? PS: I use Python 3.

Comment: @injoy: It's because the subprocess streams deal in byte-strings rather than Unicode-strings. See [this page](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) for some introductory information on the differences.

Comment: use `p = Popen("./app", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE); output = p.communicate(b"3\n4")[0]; print(p.returncode)`. If you set both `stdout` and `stderr`; you need to read both streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output `b''` means "an empty byte string".

This is because there is no `stdout` output to deliver, because your subprocess has not launched successfully.

Your example works for me as desired if I open the subprocess as `"./app"` but not if I just say `"app"`.  Presumably this is because, on unix-like systems (unlike Windows), the current working directory is not on the shell path by default, so `"app"` is simply not found.

If you had said

```
print(p.stderr.read())
```

then it could have told you what the problem was itself.